# Time complexity in this method (Big O)

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm stuck at finding the time complexity of this method. There's som queries to a db that i don't think should be taken into account. Is anyone here a master at doing things like this? I have tried looking at guides and videoes but most of them are with examples that's no where near the size of this one, and i must admit that i really suck at math so it's hard to wrap my head around it when it becomes more than two loops. Is it just O(n^3) when you don't take the DB into account?

```
public List<HotelRoom> getSuitableHotelRooms(Date startDate, Date endDate, String roomType, int singleBedQty, int doubleBedQty) throws DataAccessException {
    boolean isCandidate = true;
    ArrayList<HotelRoom> correctTypeRooms = rctr.getFilteredHotelRooms(roomType, singleBedQty, doubleBedQty);
    ArrayList<HotelRoom> suitableRooms = new ArrayList<HotelRoom>();
    for(HotelRoom r : correctTypeRooms) {
        List<Booking> bookingsOnRoom = getBookingsByRoomnumber(r.getRoomNumber());
        if(bookingsOnRoom.isEmpty()) {
            suitableRooms.add(r);
            isCandidate = false;
        }
        else {
            boolean isWhileCandidate = true;
            while(isWhileCandidate) {
                int noOfBookingsDone = 0;
            for(Booking b : bookingsOnRoom) {
                if(startDate.before(b.getTimeEnd().getTime()) && b.getTimeStart().getTime().before(endDate)) {
                    isCandidate = false;
                    isWhileCandidate = false;
                    }
                else {
                    noOfBookingsDone++;
                    if(noOfBookingsDone>=bookingsOnRoom.size()) {
                        isWhileCandidate = false;
                    }
                }
                }

            }
        }
        if(isCandidate) {
            suitableRooms.add(r);
        }
        else {
            isCandidate = true;
        }
    }
    return suitableRooms;
}

private List<Booking> getBookingsByRoomnumber(int roomNumber) {
    ArrayList<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Booking b : this.allBookings) {
        if(b.getR().getRoomNumber()==roomNumber) {
            bookings.add(b);
        }
    }
    return bookings;
}

public ArrayList<HotelRoom> getFilteredHotelRooms(String roomType, int singleBedQty, int doubleBedQty) throws DataAccessException {
    ArrayList<HotelRoom> filteredRooms = new ArrayList<HotelRoom>();
    try {
        this.findHotelRoomByFilter.setString(1, roomType.toUpperCase());
        this.findHotelRoomByFilter.setInt(2, singleBedQty);
        this.findHotelRoomByFilter.setInt(3, doubleBedQty);
        ResultSet rs = this.findHotelRoomByFilter.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            HotelRoom r = new HotelRoom(rs.getInt("singleBedQty"), rs.getInt("doubleBedQty"), false, stringToEnum(rs.getString("roomType")));
            r.setRoomNumber(rs.getInt("roomNumber"));
            r.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
            filteredRooms.add(r);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DataAccessException("Kunne ikke filtrere listen med hotelværelser", e);
    }
    return filteredRooms;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're implying the time complexity of method `getSuitableHotelRooms` - the `while` loop does not make sense here: since `for(Booking b : bookingsOnRoom)` loop will run exactly `bookingsOnRoom.size()` times and will eventually set `isWhileCandidate` to false, `while` loop will never execute its second iteration. So considering two `for` loops here, the time complexity is `O(correctTypeRooms_size * bookingsOnRoom_size)`

(the best case is when `bookingsOnRoom.isEmpty()` for each room, in that case time complexity becomes `O(correctTypeRooms_size)`)